# How to enclose substring concatenation in single quotes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert  varchar field into date using the Convert() in SQL Server. Value of field EntryDate is 01312009. I would like to add the hyphens in the date. I have tried using the convert() like this -

```
CONVERT(date,[EntryDate],110)
```

and I keep getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've tried different formats and still errors out on me. However, when I hardcode the date with hyphens:

```
CONVERT(date,'01-31-2009')
```

I am able to get 2009-01-31 which is the format I want. I am having trouble using the actual field name enclosed in quotes. My code is below. How do I enclose in single quotes my substring concatenation?

```
Select Convert(date,'substring([EntryDate],1,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],3,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],5,4)') From DateEntries
```

Comment: While I think the STUFF method used by XMedhi01 is nicer, if you want to use the SUBSTRING approach above, you don't need the quotes around the whole substring section - only the literals (i.e., the hyphens) e.g., `Select Convert(date,substring([EntryDate],1,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],3,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],5,4))`

Comment: I get the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." when I try the statement above.

Comment: I'm guessing at least one of the dates is not in the mmddyyyy format, meaning any of the splitting/concatenations or stuffing will result in something that isn't a date. I suggest starting with just doing a SELECT on the string concatenations rather than the convert, and have a look at the results. Are any dates strange (e.g., if the date skipped the initial 0)? Also, similar to my comment on @XMedhi01's post - it's best to provide a style for the convert e.g., `Select Convert(date,substring([EntryDate],1,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],3,2) + '-' + substring([EntryDate],5,4), 110)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the code - CONVERT(date,substring([Date Admission],1,2) + '-' + substring([Date Admission],3,2) + '-' + substring([Date Admission],5,4),110) - to included the style 110 and I still get an error. The odd thing was for a split second, it looked like it would display the results but then it errored out eventually.

Comment: It is likely that at least one of the dates is not in mmddyyyy format. If it's not, adding dashes won't make it a date - and trying to convert it would fail. Personally, I suggest just doing a SELECT with the substring/concatenation component first, and look at the data. Are any of them not dates?

Comment: The best solution would be to convert the field from type `varchar` to type `Date` It is never ever a good idea to store information in other field types then they are supposed to be, you are now finding out why. Once the column has the correct field type, formatting it is a lot more simple, but I would suggest to let the client application do that formatting, it is much better equipped than sql to do that

Comment: @seanb - it turns out that there were a few rows  with bad data in them that was causing the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert string date in format 'DD-MM-YYYY', So you can [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it into date:

```sql
DECLARE @EntryDate VARCHAR(8);
SET @EntryDate = '01312009';
DECLARE @realDate DATE;
SET @realDate = CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(@EntryDate, 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-')); --CONVERT(DATE, '01-31-2009')
SELECT @realDate AS MyDate; --'2009-01-31'
```

Explanation of `Stuff` of how to insert hyphens (-):

> STUFF ( character_expression , start , length ,
> replace_with_expression )

- `STUFF(@EntryDate, 5, 0, '-')`: This replaces nothing (0 characters `length`), `start` at the 5th position: `'0131-2009'`.
- `STUFF('0131-2009', 3, 0, '-')`: This replaces nothing (0 characters `length`), `start` at the 3rd position: `'01-31-2009'`.

*Note: SQL Server's `STUFF` function, the starting position is **1-based**, not **0-based**.*

Comment: I would also suggest explicitly setting the style (as 110) in the CONVERT e.g., `CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(@EntryDate, 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-'), 110)` to ensure that ambiguous initial varchar dates (e.g., 01-02-2009) are handled correctly - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles

Comment: I've added more explanation of how `stuff` function works!

Comment: Hi. I tried the code - CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(EntryDate, 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-')) - but I still get the same error - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: @jbpm I already try it on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSZVg-ES) and convert it correctly into date!

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. In your answer, you're setting a variable with a hard-coded value. I was hoping to convert a SQL table field and not a  single specific value

Comment: I answered as you asked, till now there's no problem just give more details and I'll try to answer you in the table not hard-coded value

Comment: I think if there are many records on the table, Maybe some records aren't in that format `DDMMYYYY`, So try to use function [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to ignore if the error conversion!